# What is an "order line"?

Tags: data-modeling

I listen a number of podcasts. Often I hear the expression "Order line" in the context of database or business object modelling. It seems to be the canonical example of something. I just don't know what.

So what is an "order line"? What concept does it represent in a canonical example?

Comment: It might help if you described (by pointing to with a URL) an example of a podcast that mentions this.

Comment: I hear it in ecommerce specifically. It refers to the items an order consists of (the lines of the order).

Comment: I assume that this is most likely a very stupid question, but I would rather be stupid now, than the next time I hear "order line" in a podcast/conversation.

Comment: @DonalFellows One example would be: http://distributedpodcast.com/2011/episode-007-interview-with-ayende-rahien

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It refers to a "Purchase Order" which typically consists of one or more lines, called "Order Lines".

As almost every business on earth has some similar record of its orders, purchases and/or sales, it has been the canonical real-world data example of a Parent-Child (or Master-Detail) relationship for as long as databases have existed (well over forty years).

It might look like this:

```
May Weller,    14-FEB-2011

    qty    Product          Price

      1    Hose, 50ft       $21.99
      4    Sprinkler        $33.78
      1    Gum              $ 1.10

Total                       $56.87
```

This would typically be stored as one row in an [ORDERS] table and three additional rows in an [Order-Lines] table, that all point back to the parent row in [ORDERS].  Which could look something like this:

**[ORDERS] Table:**

```
OrderID:        14028
Customer:       May Weller
OrderDate:      14-FEB-2011
```

**[OrderLines] Table:**

```
OrderLineID:    223011      223012      223013
OrderID:        14028       14028       14028
quantity:       1           4           1
Product:        Hose, 50ft  Sprinkler   Gum
Price:          21.99       33.78       1.10
```

(NOTE: yes, I know that this is not fully normalized yet).

Answer (score 3):

In simpler terms, [link](http://en.termwiki.com/EN/order_line) defines it as the part of a sales order or purchase order that specifies the detailed information about a requested item.

the table with the detailed information would typically look like RBarry's OrderLines table.