# Rails saving array with the duplicated elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm populating an array with multiple elements (some of then are equals, thats what I want). My code is something like this:

```
def create
@order = Order.create()
@order.table = Table.find_by(:number => params['table'][0])
@products ||= []
@qtd = []
Product.all.each do |product|
  params['order'].each_pair do |ordered|
    if(product.id.to_s == ordered.first)
      for i in 0..ordered.second[0].to_i
        @order.products << product
        @order.save
      end
    end
  end
end

 binding.pry #here the @order.products is the way I want to

if @order.save
  flash[:success] = "Pedido criado com sucesso."
  redirect_to tables_path
else
  flash[:danger] = "Erro ao criar pedido."
  render :new
end
end
```

But When I go to rails console and do Order.last.products he dosen't show me de duplicated elements like I saved on my controller. Whats happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in your case you should be sending order information from client to server like

```
"order"=>{"line_items_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"quantity"=>"4", "id"=>"127"}}}
```

Instead of repeating the `product` id in the list, your should implement a concept of `line items` in your system. `Line Items` are the objects representing items that are added to your shopping cart and instead of repeating the `product_id` you can use term `quantity`.

Now you can have separate model called `LineItem`. `Order` can have many `LineItem`s. `LineItem` has many `products`.

For more info see [What is a "order line"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367206/what-is-a-order-line)

---

**For current Implementation:**

`<<` method does not allow duplicate entries. It filters out the duplicates. Its basically relates `products` with `order` since `order` can have multiple `products` via `some_table`. It cannot relate same `product` to the `order` twice.

My suggestion would be, create a `string` field(column) called `products` and add the serialized array of product ids.

```
order.products = [1, 1, 3, 4,4,4].to_s
```

while accessing you de-serialize.

Comment: The first solution worked just the way I wanted! Thank you :)