# How to record customer purchases?

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

[image: Simplified ERD]

I am creating a database which keeps track of customers, items, transactions, and more. I am having trouble describing the relationship between `Customers` and `Items` which is represented by `buys`. The relationship, `buys`, represents a `Customer` purchasing `Items` at a register. The transaction, `buys`, may include one item, multiple items, and/or the same item multiple times in a single transaction; additionally, multiple `Customers` may purchase the same item on separate occasions.

***What attributes does the relationship `buys` need in order to keep track of all the items purchased?***

Currently, I am proposing an attribute `buys.id`; however, it seems a composite key is necessary. The keys could (`buys.id`, `Customer.id`, `Items.id`), yet if a customer were to add the same item twice, then these rules would break. I would also include a `date` attribute. Additionally, a `quantity` attribute could be added to relationship.

The relationship could be described like so:
[image: Relationship 2]

It does appear that this would be able to satisfy all the rules laid forth, but it seems a bit cumbersome.

***Is there a way to improve this design?***

(I need a refresher on this stuff if anybody knows a good book or video)

EDIT:

[This answer from another post could answer this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10367237/6742108)

I'm using MariaDB and python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making your model bigger should always be something to be wary of, but in this case you may be missing a concept: [order lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367206/what-is-an-order-line).

Since you didn't specify a stack in your question, I'll plug in [this python class](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/blob/f00361947283ae16af92c1766e4eb63ac36fcf23/saleor/order/models.py#L379) from a somewhat popular project.

I'll also advise anyone reading this to always, always look on popular open-source projects *how they did it* if there is even a remote chance you are working on something that has been done before when hitting a wall (perhaps before, but never stop thinking how could you make it simpler!)!

Not only its a great way to see how people usually model stuff and use a shared/common language but you may learn some pitfalls and problems you may run into.

Comment: BTW in the real world this gets insanely more complicated. Say, how do you deal with time-limited stuff? With a coupom? Metered? Fraud? Billing is such a central topic for as long as bills existed that people kill eachother to try and have it working. We'll get there tho :D,

Comment: that is why I spent several hours reading about the various ways to store phone numbers and the pros and cons of keeping the country code, area code, and the phone number separate. What about the proper way storing addresses? There is no proper way from what I can tell since it is possible for different countries to have different standards. The USPS has set forth standards for American addresses, but that is not necessarily universal.

Comment: Right? Global business is such a hard topic. I was kind with my answer btw, because due to various contract laws in various countries this gets easily to ~200 tables just to store your relationship with someone that paid for a given service.