# Derived Composite Key using JPA 1.0 Annotations (composite key-many-to-one)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

[image]

I have a simple relationship as shown in the diagram above.

I can persist this using the following Hibernate Mapping:

```
<class name="Strategy" table="Strategy">
    <id name="id" column="StrategyId" unsaved-value="any">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="status" column="Status"/>
</class>

<class name="Alert" table="Alert">
    <id name="id" column="AlertId">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="Name"/>        
</class>

<class name="StrategyAlert" table="StrategyAlert">
    <composite-id>            
        <key-many-to-one name="strategy" class="Strategy" column="StrategyId"/>
        <key-many-to-one name="alert" class="Alert" column="AlertId"/>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="nominal" column="Nominal"/>
</class>
```

I am having a really hard time trying to figure out how to do this using Annotations in JPA 1.0.

Here's what I've got so far:

Alert Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ALERT")
public class Alert implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ALERTID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;    
}
```

Strategy Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STRATEGY")
public class Strategy implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)    
    @Column(name="STRATEGYID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="STATUS")
    private String status;
}
```

StrategyAlertPK class:

```
public class StrategyAlertPK implements Serializable {

    private int strategyId;
    private int alertId;
}
```

StrategyAlert class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STRATEGYALERT")
@IdClass(StrategyAlertPK.class)
public class StrategyAlert implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="STRATEGYID")
    private int strategyId;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ALERTID")
    private int alertId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="STRATEGYID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Strategy strategy;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ALERTID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Alert alert;

    @Column
    private String nominal;
}
```

Test Case:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();       
Alert alert = new Alert();
alert.setName("NAME");
em.persist(alert);

Strategy strategy = new Strategy();
strategy.setStatus("STATUS");        
em.persist(strategy);

StrategyAlert strategyAlert = new StrategyAlert();
strategyAlert.setAlert(alert);
strategyAlert.setStrategy(strategy);
strategyAlert.setNominal("NOMINAL");
em.persist(strategyAlert);        
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I'm getting the following error:

Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK80432DA9CE00672E: PUBLIC.STRATEGYALERT FOREIGN KEY(STRATEGYID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.STRATEGY(STRATEGYID) (0)

I'm using `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />` to generate the tables.

**How do I annotate the StrategyAlert class correctly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this questions: [How to implement a complex many to many relationship in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130494/how-to-implement-a-complex-many-to-many-relationship-in-jpa)

I think the problem here is you have to join the Id declaration and the manyToOne declaration as described in JPA 1, I can´t test the code right now, but more or less it has to be like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STRATEGYALERT")
@IdClass(StrategyAlertPK.class)
public class StrategyAlert implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="STRATEGYID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   private Strategy strategy;

   @Id
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="ALERTID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   private Alert alert;

   @Column
   private String nominal;

   // TODO Getters and setters
}
```

**UPDATE**

Hi,

now I can test the code, and is working for m with the following code (some minors corrections):

```
/**
 * 
 */
package hib;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="ALERT")
public class Alert implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ALERTID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Strategy

```
/**
 * 
 */
package hib;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="STRATEGY")
public class Strategy implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)    
    @Column(name="STRATEGYID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="STATUS")
    private String status;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the status
     */
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    /**
     * @param status the status to set
     */
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

StrategyAlertPK

```
/**
 * 
 */
package hib;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

/**
 *
 */
@Embeddable
public class StrategyAlertPK implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private Strategy strategy;

    @ManyToOne
    private Alert alert;
    /**
     * @return the strategy
     */
    public Strategy getStrategy() {
        return strategy;
    }
    /**
     * @param strategy the strategy to set
     */
    public void setStrategy(Strategy strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }
    /**
     * @return the alert
     */
    public Alert getAlert() {
        return alert;
    }
    /**
     * @param alert the alert to set
     */
    public void setAlert(Alert alert) {
        this.alert = alert;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        StrategyAlertPK that = (StrategyAlertPK) o;

        if (strategy != null ? !strategy.equals(that.strategy) : that.strategy != null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (alert != null ? !alert.equals(that.alert) : that.alert != null) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        result = (strategy != null ? strategy.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (alert != null ? alert.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }


}
```

StrategyAlert

```
/**
 * 
 */
package hib;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="STRATEGYALERT")
    @AssociationOverrides({ @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.strategy", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "STRATEGYID")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.alert", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ALERTID")) })
public class StrategyAlert implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private StrategyAlertPK pk = new StrategyAlertPK();

    @Column
    private String nominal;

    @Transient
    public Strategy getStrategy() {
        return pk.getStrategy();
    }

    public void setStrategy(Strategy strategy) {
        pk.setStrategy(strategy);
    }

    @Transient
    public Alert getAlert() {
        return pk.getAlert();
    }

    public void setAlert(Alert alert) {
        pk.setAlert(alert);
    }

    /**
     * @return the nominal
     */
    public String getNominal() {
        return nominal;
    }

    /**
     * @param nominal the nominal to set
     */
    public void setNominal(String nominal) {
        this.nominal = nominal;
    }
}
```

With that code your test is running OK (I tested it with JPA 1.0.1, Hibernate 3.3.1.GA and spring 2.5.5). I am using H2 as memory database so I had to change Identity to AUTO in generated values, maybe you don´t need to do that.

Hope helps!

Comment: Thanks for help Francisco I tried that and I get an error that the Id Class can't find it's properties:   "Unable to find properties (alertId, strategyId) in entity annotated with @IdClass:hib.StrategyAlert"

Comment: I have tried everything I can think of and I cannot get this to work. Considering how easy it is in XML you would think it should be easy enough using Annotations.  Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer, now I can test the code and is working for me. Hope helps

Comment: I'm also using H2.I copy/pasted your code just renamed package to hib. I'm getting the following error: `Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of hib.StrategyAlertPK.alert` and `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field hib.StrategyAlertPK.alert to hib.Alert`.  Im using HIbernate  v3.2.4 I might try another version as I can't see why this is happening.

Comment: I tried it with latest version of Hibernate I can use - v3.3.1.GA / Annotations 3.4.0.GA / EntityManager 3.4.0.GA and I get exact same error: `Can not set int field hib.StrategyAlertPK.alert to hib.Alert`. I don't know what to try next

Comment: Sorry! My mistake. I updated the answer, I changed only StrategyAlertPK, The PK class must have its attributes as entities, not as primitive types. Change it and try again

Comment: I tried that and it does persist the values but it looks like it's serializing the objects instead of storing the IDs. The Strategy Column contains `aced0005737200096869622e416c657274dbd1f96fcd2ddb5c02000249000269644c00046e616d657400124c6a6176612f6c616e672f537472696e673b7870000000017400044e414d45` and the alert column contains something similar and both are VARBINARY

Comment: Hi, new update. I Changed StrategyAlertPK and StrategyAlert, I Think this is the good one. Try it out! :D

Comment: Brilliant - that works! Thanks for figuring it out I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution but I don't think this is the correct way to do it.

I have a static nested class for the ID.  Then in both setter methods I also set the ID.  This seems a very manual way to do it and surely there must be a better way?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STRATEGYALERT")
public class StrategyAlert {

    @Embeddable
    public static class Id implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8270591004786497335L;

        @Column(name="STRATEGYID")
        private int strategyId;

        @Column(name="ALERTID")
        private int alertId;

        public Id() {}

        public Id(int strategyId, int alertId) {
            this.strategyId = strategyId;
            this.alertId = alertId;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + alertId;
            result = prime * result + strategyId;
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if(this == obj)
                return true;
            if(obj == null)
                return false;
            if(getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Id other = (Id)obj;
            if(alertId != other.alertId)
                return false;
            if(strategyId != other.strategyId)
                return false;
            return true;
        }

    }    

    @EmbeddedId
    private Id id = new Id();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="STRATEGYID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Strategy strategy;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ALERTID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Alert alert;

    @Column(name="NOMINAL")
    private String nominal;    

    public StrategyAlert() {}

    public void setStrategy(Strategy strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;    
        // SET ID
        this.id.strategyId = strategy.getId();
    }

    public void setAlert(Alert alert) {
        this.alert = alert;    
        // SET ID
        this.id.alertId = alert.getId();
    }

    // Other Getters & Setters...
}
```