# ManyToMany on itself with AssociationTable with EmbeddedId - Spring-Data-Jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have some trouble with Hibernate during a ManyToMany association :/
I want to have a user with his contacts.
The association Table is used to have a creation_date of the association and her status (ex. Active, inactive, etc...)

- Hibernate version : 5.2.17
- Spring boot : 2.0.5

**My class USER :**

```
@Entity(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "assoc_user_user", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = 
"id.myself.id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = 
"id.contact.id")})
private List<AssocUserUser> contacts;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "assoc_user_user", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = 
"id.contact.id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = 
"id.myself.id")})
private List<AssocUserUser> contactOf;

}
```

**My Association class AssocUserUser :**

```
@Entity(name = "assoc_user_user")
public class AssocUserUser implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private AssocUserUserId id;

@Column(name = "creation_date", nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime creationDate;

@Column(name = "status")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ContactStatusEnum status;

}
```

**My EmbeddedId class AssocUserUserId :**

```
@Embeddable
public class AssocUserUserId implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id_myself", nullable = false)
private User myself;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id_contact", nullable = false)
private User contact;

}
```

**My Error :**

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering
>   com.....AssocUserUser from com.....User has the wrong number of
>   column. should be 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this question has been asked and answered at [Spring-Data-JPA ManyToMany relationship with extra column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52648330/spring-data-jpa-manytomany-relationship-with-extra-column) but I guess it's a little different with the self reference. I'm not a big fan of all the `JoinTable` and `JoinColumn` annotations but only because they are generally redundant and, IMHO, meant for changing the defaults. My answer doesn't include those annotations so add them as needed. Note that with Spring-Data-Jpa you need repositories for each entity and so you need a repository for the Association Entity. This is different than a single entity manager in JPA. This affects a little bit how you deal with the Association Entity. Here we persist new relationships by creating and persisting new `AssocUserUser` entities.

The way I've done the classes is:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="myself")
    private Set<AssocUserUser> contacts;

@Entity
public class AssocUserUser {
    @EmbeddedId
    private AssocUserUserId id = new AssocUserUserId();
    @ManyToOne @MapsId("myselfId")
    private User myself;
    @ManyToOne @MapsId("contactId")
    private User contact;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Embeddable
public class AssocUserUserId implements Serializable {
    private Long myselfId;
    private Long contactId;
```

and `Repositories` for both entities

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("select u from User u left outer join fetch u.contacts where u.id = :userId")
    User getContactsForUser(@Param("userId") Long userId);

public interface AssocUserUserRepository extends JpaRepository<AssocUserUser, AssocUserUserId> {
```

How to create the association

```
private void update() {
    User user1 = new User();
    User contact1 = new User();
    userRepo.save(user1);
    userRepo.save(contact1);
    AssocUserUser assoc = new AssocUserUser();
    assoc.setMyself(user1);
    assoc.setContact(contact1);
    assocUserUserRepo.save(assoc);
}
```

How to read the association in a `Unidirectional` fashion

```
private void read() {
    User me = new User();
    me.setId(1L);
    AssocUserUser assoc = new AssocUserUser();
    assoc.setMyself(me);
    List<AssocUserUser> contacts = assocUserUserRepo.findAll(Example.of(assoc));
    System.out.println(contacts.size());
}
```

And to read the association in a `Bidirectional` fashion:

```
private void readBi() {
    User me = userRepo.getContactsForUser(1L);
    System.out.println(me.getContacts().size());
}
```

As always, check the logs:

```
create table assoc_user_user (contact_id bigint not null, myself_id bigint not null, primary key (contact_id, myself_id))
create table user (id bigint generated by default as identity, primary key (id))
alter table assoc_user_user add constraint FKaccetv956cu63fwiejjfrm0mi foreign key (contact_id) references user
alter table assoc_user_user add constraint FK1absxfuktrjnom8vwtjfqx5l0 foreign key (myself_id) references user

insert into user (id) values (null)
insert into user (id) values (null)
select assocuseru0_.contact_id as contact_1_0_0_, assocuseru0_.myself_id as myself_i2_0_0_ from assoc_user_user assocuseru0_ where assocuseru0_.contact_id=? and assocuseru0_.myself_id=?
select user0_.id as id1_1_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?
select user0_.id as id1_1_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?
insert into assoc_user_user (contact_id, myself_id) values (?, ?)

select assocuseru0_.contact_id as contact_1_0_, assocuseru0_.myself_id as myself_i2_0_ from assoc_user_user assocuseru0_ inner join user user1_ on assocuseru0_.myself_id=user1_.id where user1_.id=1
select user0_.id as id1_1_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?
select user0_.id as id1_1_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?

select user0_.id as id1_1_0_, contacts1_.contact_id as contact_1_0_1_, contacts1_.myself_id as myself_i2_0_1_, contacts1_.myself_id as myself_i2_0_0__, contacts1_.contact_id as contact_1_0_0__ from user user0_ left outer join assoc_user_user contacts1_ on user0_.id=contacts1_.myself_id where user0_.id=?
select user0_.id as id1_1_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?
```

Comment: Thanks for your HUGE help ! :)

Yes i did a new post because to the itself

". I didn't know about @MapsId ! Thanks so much, the answer is very complete and usefull.

Comment: I noticed you only have one contacts association in User entity and deleted the inverse contactOf relationship. Why is that?