# Detached entity passed to persist many to many with extra column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to create a many to many relationship with a extra column. I configured this:

```
@Entity
public class Configuration extends AbstractEntity {

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "configuration",
            cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<ConfigurationQuestion> configurationQuestions = new ArrayList<>();


    public void addQuestion(QuestionDTO question) {
        ConfigurationQuestion configurationQuestion = new ConfigurationQuestion(this,
                question.getQuestion(), question.getResponse());

        configurationQuestions.add(configurationQuestion);
    }

}
```

Join table

```
@Entity
public class ConfigurationQuestion implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ConfigurationQuestionId id ;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("configurationId")
    private Configuration configuration;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId("questionId")
    @JoinColumn(name="question_id")
    private Question question;

    private Integer response; 

    public ConfigurationQuestion(Configuration configuration, Question question,
                                 Integer response) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.question = question;
        this.response = response;
        this.id = new ConfigurationQuestionId(configuration.getId(), question.getId());
    }

}
```

Embedable id

```
@Embeddable
public class ConfigurationQuestionId implements Serializable {

    private Long configurationId;

    private Long questionId;
}
```

In question I don't have any mapping I want to do it one directional. My problem is when I try to save something like this. I want to save a configuration that have as question just ids not the entire object, it is saved separatly.

In Question entity I don't have any mapping I want to do it one directional. My problem is when I try to save something like this. I want to save a configuration that has as question/questions just ids not the entire objects, it is saved separately.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
Question question = new Question();
question.setId(1L);

configuration.addQuestion(new QuestionDTO(question, 1));

repository.save(configuration);
```

I receive the following error. I don't want to cascade the changes to Question entity, if I remove Cascade.ALL from Configuration isn't inserting anything in the join table. Can I do this without making a find for questions?

```
detached entity passed to persist: Question
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ManyToMany on itself with AssociationTable with EmbeddedId - Spring-Data-Jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757254/manytomany-on-itself-with-associationtable-with-embeddedid-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: @K.Nicholas That answer is not even related to the OP's question.

Comment: Same thing. "How do I work with ManyToMany associations in spring-data-jpa". He wanted a unidirectional answer and that and more is in there.

Comment: No it is completely different. The answer you linked was about an entity referring to itself. This is simply about adding a foreign key reference to another *different* entity when you *know its primary key* so you don't want to incur the overheads of querying the entity from the database.

Comment: Can you give me a hit about how i can avoid firing the database for questions?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to `Cascade` your changes from the `Configuration` entity to the `Question` entity you have to save it separately. The JPA provider is right to complain that the entity passed is still detached. It is still just a plain old java object instance, the JPA `EntityManager` does not know about it.

Try to save the `Question` separately first before saving the `Configuration` entity.

If you already have the `Question` in the database, know its ID, but want to avoid getting it completely you can use the [`getReference()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object)) method, which returns a proxy for your `Entity`. There will still be some overhead by the JPA provider to verify the instance exists (it should throw an `EntityNotFoundException` if it does not exist), but should be more lightweight.

If you are using a Spring Data `JpaRepository` there is a similar method, awkwardly named [`getOne()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-) which does essentially the same thing (it calls the `EntityManager.getReference()`).

Comment: I save Question separately. But when I want to save Configuration I want to have in ConfigurationQuestion questions with only ids like in exemple. There is a question with id = 1 saved in database.When I save Configuration I want to save Configuration and the relationship from ConfigurationQuestion.

Comment: That is not what you are doing in your example. You are creating a completely new `Question` and just setting the `id` to `1`, without setting the rest of the fields. JPA can't know that you just want it to take the `id` from the `Question` entity. The model you have is wrong.

Comment: Can i specify not the persist the Question and just add it in the join table?

Comment: I updated the answer, I think this is what you really want to do. Get a reference to the existent `Question` entity without having to actually retrieve it from the database unless you really need to.